# Conflict between libtwolame0 and libtwolame0:i386

Tags: debian, package-management

I am trying to install Skype on *Debian Stretch (testing) amd64* (`skype-debian_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb`), which depends on `libasound2-plugins:i386` which itself transitively depends on `libtwolame0:i386`. Multiarch is already set and working on my machine.

But apparently, there is a conflict between `libtwolame0` (amd64 version) and `libtwolame0:i386`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libtwolame0 libtwolame0:i386
[...]
libtwolame0 is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libtwolame0 : Conflicts: libtwolame0:i386 but 0.3.13-1.1 is to be installed
libtwolame0:i386 : Conflicts: libtwolame0 but 0.3.13-1.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ sudo apt-cache showpkg libtwolame0
Package: libtwolame0
Versions: 
0.3.13-1.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.fr.debian.org_debian_dists_stretch_ma [...]
[...]

Reverse Depends: 
libtwolame0:i386,libtwolame0 
vlc-nox,libtwolame0
twolame,libtwolame0
libtwolame-dev,libtwolame0 0.3.13-1.1
libsox-fmt-mp3,libtwolame0
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly,libtwolame0
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly,libtwolame0
libavcodec-ffmpeg56,libtwolame0
darkice,libtwolame0
audacity,libtwolame0
Dependencies: 
0.3.13-1.1 - libc6 (2 2.3.4) libtwolame0:i386 (0 (null)) # Why libtwolame0:i386 ?
```

How can I know if it is a general Debian issue or an issue with my installation? If it is an issue with my installation, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the `twolame` packages, tracked as [#777223](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=777223). There's a pending upload which should go into `unstable` on Sunday; you'll be able to fix your system then (or five days later in `stretch`).

In the meantime, you can revert to the previous version of `libasound2-plugins` ([`amd64`](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140831T043039Z/pool/main/a/alsa-plugins/libasound2-plugins_1.0.28-1%2Bb1_amd64.deb) and [`i386`](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140831T043039Z/pool/main/a/alsa-plugins/libasound2-plugins_1.0.28-1%2Bb1_i386.deb)), then hold them until `libtwolame0` is available; that should fix your system right now.